# Xcode project files disappear from left navigator after merging master into branch

Tags: xcode, git, github

I am working in a small iOS team and tried merging the master branch into another branch. After I resolve merge conflicts, all the project files disappear from the left Xcode navigator. When I click on the project target in Xcode, it shows this popup:

[image: Project files disappear.]

I'm also getting an error that says the project cannot be loaded:

[image: Cannot load project error.]

This might or might not be helpful in finding the solution, but I'm also failing a check on Github from Xcode Cloud saying I'm missing a scheme:

[image: Failed Github check]

[image: Failed Github check]

I have literally no idea what to do. What might be causing this issue, and how can I fix it?

One other dev on my team tried to remove a git ignore file that was committed earlier, but it didn't solve the problem. I've experienced this problem before and I think I resolved it by pressing git revert, but I cannot do that again.

Comment: Your project file probably has conflicts. You will need to fix them in some text editor before you can open it in Xcode.

Comment: "After I resolve merge conflicts" it sounds like you did that wrong. Reset hard to before the merge, to undo the merge, and try again. Look carefully at what the merge will do before letting it go through. Don't worry, we've all been there! Everything is undoable.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.